# What's this? [field:SecurityCritical]

Tags: c#

Looking at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher (as decompiled by Reflector) I came across;

```
[field: SecurityCritical]
public event DispatcherUnhandledExceptionFilterEventHandler UnhandledExceptionFilter;
```

I don't recognize the 'field' part of the attribute declaration, what is it?

**Edit:**

This is how it appears in the reference source:

```
    public event DispatcherUnhandledExceptionFilterEventHandler UnhandledExceptionFilter
    { 
        [SecurityCritical] 
        [UIPermissionAttribute(SecurityAction.LinkDemand,Unrestricted=true)]
        add 
        {
            _unhandledExceptionFilter += value;
        }
        [SecurityCritical] 
        [UIPermissionAttribute(SecurityAction.LinkDemand,Unrestricted=true)]
        remove 
        { 
            _unhandledExceptionFilter -= value;
        } 
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`field:` is called an attribute target.  It lets you specify the target (assembly, return, etc.) for the attribute.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3787ac0.aspx for more details.

Comment: Going against the flow of the votes, this actually answers my question what is 'field', and you got in just before Alex, so you win :)

Comment: @panamack - Not sure if 'Alex' refers to me, but I answered first. If you hover over `answered X hours ago`, you will see the exact timestamp. Compare the timestamps.

Comment: @Alex, enjoy your moral victory ;p.

Comment: @panamack - what does it mean?

Answer (score 6):

It just means that it's applying the attribute to the delegate that's backing the event, rather than the event itself.

Just like how property syntax is a shorthand, the code

```
event MyDelegate MyEvent;
```

is actually shorthand for

```
MyDelegate _BackingDelegate;

event MyDelegate MyEvent
{
    add { lock (this._BackingDelegate) this._BackingDelegate += value; }
    remove { lock (this._BackingDelegate) this._BackingDelegate -= value; }
}
```

IIRC*, and that attributes applies to `_BackingDelegate` and not `MyEvent`.

<sub>*Note: I'm not sure if there is a `lock` statement or not, but I *think* there is.</sub>

Comment: Yes, I've just looked at the reference source and the attribute is in fact applied to the add and remove accessors.

Comment: @panamack: Wait, what? It's applied to the accessors, or to the field?!

Comment: @panamack: I'm a little confused, but in any case, if what I'm saying is the reverse of what's actually happening, do let me know... I'm fairly sure this is right, though...

Comment: @Mehrdad, I suppose since Reflector is decompiling from the IL then depending on how the original code compiles, it may interpret it as applied to a field although when it was written it was applied to the event accessors, I'm just guessing there though.

Comment: @panamack: Yeah idk, it might be a good idea to check ILDASM.

Answer (score 3):

The syntax for attribute targets is the following:

```
[target : attribute-list]
```

Where target is one of the following: assembly, field, event, method, module, param, property, return, type.

You can find the full list of possible targets here: [Disambiguating Attribute Targets](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3787ac0.aspx)

`SecurityCritical` cannot by applied to the event. But it can be applied to the backing EventHanlder field.

Answer (score 1):

When you declare attribute for event, you have the option to apply the attribute either to the event itself or to the field that hold the event's delegate to the generated `add` and `remove` methods. The specifier `field` means the attribute is applied to the field.

See [Disambiguating Attribute Targets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3787ac0.aspx) on MSDN and also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5482522/41071).